# Why isn't this grid displaying correctly?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a portfolio page as an excuse project to learn HTML/CSS, but I'm constantly having problems trying to position elements correctly.

One good adaptive solution that I was able to make work is using grid containers to organize the layout.

But for some reason I just can't make this container grid work as the others. I want the title top center, and one button on each side of the title, with the image being displayed alone on the next row, and then a description text on the last row.

However, for some reason, the left button goes to the second row and gets stuck right next to the image.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="containerport">
    <div class="botton">
        <img src="img/botãoblank1.png" style="width:30px,height:30px">
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
        <h1>01</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="botton">
        <a href="mainp2.html">
            <img src="img/botão2.png" style="width:30px,height:30px">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
         <img src="img/01.png">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
         <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.containerport {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-areas:
       "botton heading botton"
       "item item item"
       "text text text";
   grid-gap: 10px;
   padding-top: 25px;
   padding-bottom: 25px;
   width: 60%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;width:100%;">
    <div class="botton"><img src="img/botãoblank1.png" style="width:30px,height:30px"></div>
    <div class="heading" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><h1>01</h1></div>
    <div class="botton"><a href="mainp2.html"><img src="img/botão2.png" style="width:30px,height:30px"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="item"><img src="img/01.png"></div>
<div class="text"><p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p></div>
```

Comment: Oh cool, it kinda worked. But now the image is in the same Row as the buttons and the heading. I'm trying to figure out why it refuses to move to another row.

Comment: which image? 01.png is on another row.

Answer (score 0):

1. You were using the same class name for two *div*, and that causes a problem.
2. You can use `grid-template-columns` &
   `grid-template-rows`. I couldn't find why `grid-template-areas`
   is not working.
3. Read more about *CSS Grid* here     [A Complete Guide to Grid | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
.containerport { 
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button {
  grid-column: 1/ 2;
  grid-row: 1/ 2;
}

.heading {
  grid-column: 2/ 3;
  grid-row: 1/ 2;
}

.button2 {
  grid-column: 3/ 4;
  grid-row: 1/ 2;
}

.item {
  grid-column: 1/ 4;
  grid-row: 2/ 3;
}

.text {
  grid-column: 1/ 4;
  grid-row: 3/ 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerport">
  <div class="botton">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  </div>
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>01</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="botton2">
    <a href="mainp2.html">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1: You had two divs with the same class name, because of this the program won't know with should be where.

2: You didn't set the grid-areas, they show the program what div class should be placed where. This is needed since grids can be used to set them in any order, not necessarily the order set in the HTML.

If you want to have the item centred, change the first and third one in the "grid-template-areas" to dots instead, then there will be an empty space there instead.

```css
.containerport { 
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
    "botton heading botton2"
    "item item item"
    "text text text";
    grid-gap: 10px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    width: 60%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.botton {
    grid-area: botton;
 }
.botton2 {
    grid-area: botton2;
}
.heading {
    grid-area: heading;
}
.item {
    grid-area: item;
}
.text {
    grid-area: text;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="containerport">
      <div class="botton">
        <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:30px,height:30px"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="heading">
        <h1>01</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="botton2">
        <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:30px,height:30px"></a> 
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```